# Get number of pages of external PDF

Tags: pdf, external-files, metadata

Is there a possibility to get the total number of pages of an external PDF file within a LaTeX document?

Assuming that there exists a PDF file `test.pdf` with 8 pages in the same directory my LaTeX file is saved in. Here's my very basic approach:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand \pdfnumberofpages { m } {
  % Do some magic
}

\begin{document}

\texttt{test.pdf}: \pdfnumberofpages{test.pdf} pages

\end{document}
```

The resulting document should then contain

> test.pdf: 8 pages

I know it should be possible somehow (`pdfpages` must do something like this), but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394029/87678

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After `\tracingmacros1` with option `pages=last-1`, it seems like `pdfpages` uses a feature of `pdf(la)tex` to get the number.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
    \pdfximage{test-29.pdf}
    \the\pdflastximagepages\ pages
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's really easy! Thank you! I also looked at `pdfpages`, but it was too much for me and I couldn't find the relevant command.

Comment: To the reader: Contrary to what one might expect, `\pdfximage` does *not* embed the pdf as an image. The document shown compiles to an empty page with the text `… pages` – just as I wanted :)

Answer (score 24):

### pdfTeX, LuaTeX

`\pdflastximageages`, see the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198095/16967) of Symbol 1.

**Remarks:**

- `\pdfximage` cannot be used in DVI mode.

### LuaTeX

Unhappily, LuaTeX is constantly changing its interfaces.
`\luatexluaescapestring` was renamed to `\luaescapestring` and
the library `epdf` was replaced by the library `pdfe`.
The following example was developed and tested with 1.15.0.

The number of pages can also be retrieved via the `pdfe` Lua library:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\pdfnumberofpages}[1]{%
  \directlua{%
    local doc = pdfe.open("\luaescapestring{#1}")
    local pages
    if (doc) then
      pages = pdfe.getnofpages(doc)
    else
      pages = 0
    end
    tex.write(pages)
  }%
}

\begin{document}
Number of pages: \pdfnumberofpages{test.pdf}
\end{document}
```

**Remarks:**

- If the document does not exists, the macro `\pdfnumberofpages` returns zero.
- `\pdfnumberofpages` is full expandable. Therefore it can be used in
  counter assignments, it can be written to a file, ...
- It also works in DVI mode.

### Older LuaTeX

The number of pages can also be retrieved via the `epdf` Lua library:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\pdfnumberofpages}[1]{%
  \directlua{%
    local doc = epdf.open("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}")
    local pages
    if (doc) then
      pages = doc:getCatalog():getNumPages()
    else
      pages = 0
    end
    tex.write(pages)
  }%
}

\begin{document}
Number of pages: \pdfnumberofpages{test.pdf}
\end{document}
```

**Remarks:**

- If the document does not exists, the macro `\pdfnumberofpages` returns zero.
- `\pdfnumberofpages` is full expandable. Therefore it can be used in
  counter assignments, it can be written to a file, ...
- It also works in DVI mode.

### XeTeX

XeTeX provides `\XeTeXpdfpagecount`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\numberofpages}[1]{%
  \the\XeTeXpdfpagecount"#1" %
}

\begin{document}
Number of pages: \numberofpages{test.pdf}
\end{document}
```

**Remarks:**

- If the file does not exists, the result is zero.
- Also this version if full expandable.

### Summary

The following example puts the different versions together:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
% XeTeX check
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname XeTeXpdfpagecount\endcsname\relax
  % pdfTeX check
  \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname pdflastximagepages\endcsname\relax
    \newcommand*{\numberofpages}[1]{%
      0%
      \errmessage{\noexpand\numberofpages is unsupported for this driver}%
    }%    
  \else
    % Definition for pdfTeX
    \ifpdf
      \newcommand*{\numberofpages}[1]{%
        \pdfximage{#1}%
        \the\pdflastximagepages
      }%
    \else
      \newcommand*{\numberofpages}[1]{%
        0%
        \errmessage{\noexpand\numberofpages is unsupported in DVI mode}%
      }%
    \fi
  \fi
  % LuaTeX check
  \typeout{LuaTeX check}
  \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\ifx\csname directlua\endcsname\relax
  \else
    \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\ifx\csname luaescapestring\endcsname\relax
      \typeout{luaescapestring is undefined}%
      \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
      \expandafter\ifx\csname luatexluaescapestring\endcsname\relax
      \typeout{luatexluaescapestring is undefined}%
      \else
        \newcommand*{\LuaEscapeString}{}%
        \let\LuaEscapeString\luatexluaescapestring
      \fi
    \else
      \newcommand*{\LuaEscapeString}{}%
      \let\LuaEscapeString\luaescapestring
    \fi
    \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\ifx\csname LuaEscapeString\endcsname\relax
    \else
      % Definition for newer LuaTeX
      \ifnum0\directlua{if pdfe then tex.write(1)end}=1 %
        \renewcommand*{\numberofpages}[1]{%
          \directlua{%
            local doc = pdfe.open("\LuaEscapeString{#1}")
            local pages
            if (doc) then
              pages = pdfe.getnofpages(doc)
            else
              pages = 0
            end
            tex.write(pages)
          }%
        }%
      \else
        % Definition for older LuaTeX
        \ifnum0\directlua{if epdf then tex.write(1)end}=1 %
          \renewcommand*{\numberofpages}[1]{%
            \directlua{%
              local doc = epdf.open("\LuaEscapeString{#1}")
              local pages
              if (doc) then
                pages = doc:getCatalog():getNumPages()
              else
                pages = 0
              end
              tex.write(pages)
            }%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
\else
  % Definition for XeTeX
  \newcommand*{\numberofpages}[1]{%
    \the\XeTeXpdfpagecount"#1" % space ends the file name scanning
  }%
\fi

\begin{document}
Number of pages: \numberofpages{test.pdf}% Should be different from \jobname.pdf
\end{document}
```

**Remarks:**

- If the `\newcommand` and `\renewcommand` are replaced by `\def` constructs, then the definition also works in plain TeX. (`\luatexluaescapestring` might be available as `\luaescapestring` or has to be enabled via `tex.enableprimitives`.)
- If the retrieval of the number of pages is not supported, an error message
  is thrown.

Comment: Wow, that's a really detailled answer! Thank you very much! Unfortunately, I only looked for `pdflatex` and that's why Symbol 1's answer is the best for me. It's too bad, that I only can accept one answer. But I voted you up!

Comment: UPDATE

With LuaTEX version 1.10 the epdf library was replaced by the pdfe library (Reference Manual April 2019 p.257)

Now, in order to get the total number of pages of an external pdf  a couple of lines must be changed. For example


    function totalnopages(filename)
     local doc = pdfe.open(filename)
     if doc then
      local pages = doc.Pages  
      local pagestotal = pdfe.getnofpages(doc)
    else
     pagestotal =0
   end
   tex.write(pagestotal)
   end

Comment: Can you update your answer for the latest versions of TeXLive (2022)? Thanks.

Comment: @SimonDispa Thanks. The constant changing of the interfaces in LuaTeX is quite annoying.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I have updated the answer for LuaTeX 1.15.0.

Comment: @PaulGaborit with a current `l3graphics` package you can do `\graphics_get_pagecount:nN {example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}\l_tmpa_tl` and then `\l_tmpa_tl` will contain the page numbers. That works with all engines.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. It deserves a new answer! :-)

Comment: @PaulGaborit I added one.

Answer (score 3):

With a current l3graphics (currently in l3experimental) you can use `\graphics_get_pagecount:nN` to retrieve the page count and then either print it or use it as page number in a `\includegraphics` command. `\graphics_get_pagecount:nN` works with all engines and also with LaTeX in dvi mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{l3graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\graphics_get_pagecount:nN {example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}\l_tmpa_tl
\l_tmpa_tl
\includegraphics[scale=0.5,page=\l_tmpa_tl]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for this simple and general solution.

Answer (score -1):

If someone is interested in a one-line command that writes the number of pages to the file `test.pdf.pages` (if `test.pdf` is the PDF file in question), the following (built upon the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198095/28685)) is working in *command prompt* under Windows 10 with MikTeX:

```
pdflatex "\documentclass{minimal}\nofiles\def\pdffile{test.pdf}\begin{document}\pdfximage{\pdffile}\newwrite\myfile\immediate\openout\myfile=\pdffile.pages\makeatletter\immediate\write\myfile{\the\pdflastximagepages}\makeatother\immediate\closeout\myfile\end{document}"
```

Together with `test.pdf.pages`, 2 unwanted files are generated: `minimal.pdf` and `minimal.log`, which can be deleted after compilation.