# How to count the generated pages from a Makefile

Tags: pdf, build-system

I would like to integrate a sanity test in my `Makefile` that builds multiple PDFs. I would like to count and compare the number of pages generated based on what `xelatex` outputs during/after the run, compare it an expected value and stop `make` to see if layout changes accidentally created too many / too few pages. What is the best/easiest way to do that?

I could `grep` for the usual page counter in the output, e.g. `[1][2][3]`, but that is prone to errors and often this counter is 1 page higher than the resulting PDF - in above example it counts to `[3]`, but the PDF contains only 2 pages.

I would like to avoid to check the PDF itself in a separate step so I don't have to "guess" its filename (which is generated in my case). In case that makes a difference, I need a solution for `xelatex`.

Comment: As a bonus question: WHY does xelatex sometimes count an additional page that is not in the PDF?

Comment: I don't see the `TeX` related content in this question yet. You could write the number of pages at the end of the document to a normal ASCII file and analyze this.

Comment: I am trying to analyze the `TeX` output (console / log) and/or return codes ... I tried to make that clearer in the OP.

Comment: what about the `Output written on filename.pdf (x pages).` in filename.log?

Comment: Thanks, I have missed that line - it seems more reliable than the `[]` values. I would gladly accept "grep for that" as an answer.

Comment: @touhami: Your turn ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am not sure, if you can do it for me many thanks, otherwise I'll ask the OP.

Comment: @touhami: Do it -- you provided the easiest way

Comment: What about `pdfinfo filename.pdf | grep Pages:`?

Comment: With a rather straightforward addition to `texloganalyser` I can get `texloganalyser -q test.log` to output `Output written on test.pdf (9 pages, 48492 bytes).` It could be a nice feature request.

Comment: @egreg That's a separate step, though, isn't it? `pdfinfo`, I mean.

Comment: @cfr Yes, it's part of Poppler

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198091/get-number-of-pages-of-external-pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways for knowing the number of pages in a PDF file.

1. Grep the log file for `Output written` that will return something like

   ```
   Output written on test.pdf (18 pages, 74251 bytes).
   ```

   (independently of the page numbering)
2. Use `pdfinfo` (that comes with Poppler), so `pdfinfo test.pdf|grep Pages` will output something like

   Pages:        18
3. Use `qpdf --show-npages test.pdf` that just outputs `18`.
4. Check this question and the answer by Heiko Oberdiek [Get number of pages of external PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198091/get-number-of-pages-of-external-pdf)

Answer (score 2):

You can write it from within `xelatex` to an external file, e.g. `\jobname.pp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totpages}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\AtEndDocument{%
    \newwrite\tempfile\newpage
    \immediate\openout\tempfile=\jobname.pp
    \immediate\write\tempfile{\theTotPages}%
    \immediate\closeout\tempfile}
\begin{document}

\blinddocument \newpage \blinddocument

\end{document}
```