# How to determine if a PDF page exists before including it?

Tags: graphics, pdf, conditionals

I want to test if a PDF contains the specified page before inserting it with `\includegraphicx[page=?]{filename.pdf}`. (Normally specifying a non-existent page generates a fatal error.) How can I do this for `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, and `lualatex`?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname page.pdf}
%PDF-1.1
1 0 obj <</Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj <</Type /Pages /Kids [3 0 R] /Count 1>>
endobj
3 0 obj<</Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Resources 4 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 70 50] /Contents 6 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj<</Font <</F1 5 0 R>>>>
endobj
5 0 obj<</Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /Helvetica>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Length 36>>
stream
BT /F1 10 Tf 20 20 Td (Page 1)Tj ET
endstream
endobj
xref
0 9
0000000000 65535 f
0000000009 00000 n
0000000056 00000 n
0000000111 00000 n
0000000210 00000 n
0000000248 00000 n
0000000315 00000 n
trailer <</Size 7/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
398
%%EOF
\end{filecontents*}
% \includepdfifhaspage{filename.pdf}{page}
\newcommand{\includepdfifhaspage}[2]{%
  \iftrue % <- what test should go here?
    \includegraphics[page=#2]{#1}%
  \else
    % do nothing
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
% insert page one of pdf:
\includepdfifhaspage{\jobname page.pdf}{1}
% insert nothing, since there is no page 2:
\includepdfifhaspage{\jobname page.pdf}{2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I extracted method from package pdfpages source code, which itself gets it from graphicx/pdftex.def it seems.

I initially looked at pdfpages doc but found no user level interface. Here is relevant documentation from its source code:

```
%    Unfortunately, |\pdflastximagepages| is not updated if |\includegraphics|
%    is used repeatedly on the same file. Heiko is aware of this and will provide
%    a solution in pdftex.def. Until then we will use the original graphicx's filename
%    from |\Gread@@pdftex|.
%    
%    \def\AM@getpagecount{%
%      \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox{\includegraphics{\AM@currentdocname}}%
%      \edef\AM@pagecount{\the\AM@lastsavedimageresourcepages}%
%    }
```

Note: possibly pdfpages should use `draft` option of `\includegraphics` in its `\AM@getpagecount`. This is what I do here.

Edit: in first version of this answer I had too easily dismissed the comments above, and trimmed too much the `pdfpages.sty` code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname page.pdf}
%PDF-1.1
1 0 obj <</Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj <</Type /Pages /Kids [3 0 R] /Count 1>>
endobj
3 0 obj<</Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Resources 4 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 70 50] /Contents 6 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj<</Font <</F1 5 0 R>>>>
endobj
5 0 obj<</Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /Helvetica>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Length 36>>
stream
BT /F1 10 Tf 20 20 Td (Page 1)Tj ET
endstream
endobj
xref
0 9
0000000000 65535 f
0000000009 00000 n
0000000056 00000 n
0000000111 00000 n
0000000210 00000 n
0000000248 00000 n
0000000315 00000 n
trailer <</Size 7/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
398
%%EOF
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
% FIX FROM pdfpages.sty TO FIX ISSUE WITH \pdflastximagepages
\let\AM@Gread@@pdftex\Gread@@pdftex
\renewcommand*{\Gread@@pdftex}[1]{%
  \xdef\AM@currentdocname@fix{#1}%
  \AM@Gread@@pdftex{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\includepdfifhaspage}[2]{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox{\includegraphics[draft]{#1}}%
  \pdfximage{\AM@currentdocname@fix}%
  \ifnum #2>\z@
   \unless\ifnum #2>\pdflastximagepages
     \includegraphics[page=#2]{#1}%
   \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% insert page one of pdf:
\includepdfifhaspage{\jobname page.pdf}{1}
% insert nothing, since there is no page 2:
\includepdfifhaspage{\jobname page.pdf}{2}
\end{document}
```

In the above, I have not handled luatex context. Ultimately, best would be for `pdfpages` package to produce user-lever `\pdfhaspage` boolean toggle. I didn't get feeling it exists already from its docs.

---

---

Edit to actually use package `pdfpages` in order for its drivers to handle xetex, luatex also.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname page.pdf}
%PDF-1.1
1 0 obj <</Type /Catalog /Pages 2 0 R>>
endobj
2 0 obj <</Type /Pages /Kids [3 0 R] /Count 1>>
endobj
3 0 obj<</Type /Page /Parent 2 0 R /Resources 4 0 R /MediaBox [0 0 70 50] /Contents 6 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj<</Font <</F1 5 0 R>>>>
endobj
5 0 obj<</Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /BaseFont /Helvetica>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<</Length 36>>
stream
BT /F1 10 Tf 20 20 Td (Page 1)Tj ET
endstream
endobj
xref
0 9
0000000000 65535 f
0000000009 00000 n
0000000056 00000 n
0000000111 00000 n
0000000210 00000 n
0000000248 00000 n
0000000315 00000 n
trailer <</Size 7/Root 1 0 R>>
startxref
398
%%EOF
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\includepdfifhaspage}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\AM@currentdocname{#1}%
  \IfFileExists{\AM@currentdocname}{%
  \AM@getpagecount
  \global\let\David@temp\AM@pagecount
  \endgroup
  \ifnum #2>\z@
   \ifnum #2>\David@temp\relax
     % NO PAGE #2 IN FILE #1\par
   \else
     \includegraphics[page=#2]{#1}%
   \fi
  \else
     % NO PAGE #2 IN FILE #1\par
  \fi}%
  {\endgroup}% file does not exist
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xinttools}
\begin{document}
% insert page one of pdf:
1: \includepdfifhaspage{\jobname page.pdf}{1}XXXX\par

% insert nothing, since there is no page 2:
2: \includepdfifhaspage{\jobname page.pdf}{2}XXXX\par

% Test plus complet


\xintFor #1 in {-1, 0, 1, 2, 3}\do {%
#1: \includepdfifhaspage{\jobname page.pdf}{#1}XXXX\par
}

\end{document}
```

CAVEAT: with xetex, the space taken by included pdf is blank. Besides, in a more extensive tests where I included from a ten pages pdf, the xelatex run appears to end correctly, but the log ends in an error and no pdf is produced. These examples use the pdf data from the OP's `filecontents*`, perhaps xetex does not like something there.

Anyway, this is a but a hack (which requires the `.pdf` extension used in file name) using some internal functionality of package `pdfpages`. Best would be if that package provided it.

Side note: brief reading left me impression some non protected end of line spaces can creep in in pdfpages code. Did not investigate, I may be saying crap.

**edit** in code above which uses package `pdfpages` the line

```
     \includegraphics[page=#2]{#1}%
```

should arguably read

```
     \includepdf[pages=#2]{#1}%
```

now that `pdfpages` is actually used.

**final note** in additional testing with some other files, I have no problem with `xetex`. Thus it might be something `xetex` dislikes in the explicit pdf file from OP.

Comment: That's helpful, thanks! I would like a solution that works with `xelatex` and `lualatex` as well.

Comment: That will do! I think there is something wrong with my hand crafted PDF that `xetex` doesn't like (I was just trying to keep it short). In my actual code there is no problems with `xetex`.

Comment: (for clarification, all the `xetex` remarks are now obsolete as @DavidPurton fixed the hand made PDF in `filecontents*`)