# latexmk command to check if PDF is not encrypted

Tags: luatex, latexmk

I am developing a website on PHP where user can uploads pdf and image files. later on I am converting including all PDF files in one pdf file with some custom text in it.

**I am using this command**

```
latexmk -lualatex -gg --output-format=pdf --interaction=batchmode "sample.tex"
```

which is working absolutely fine.

only problem is sometimes, when user uploads .heic images or password protected images, it gives error.

so my question is there any command of latexmk from which you can directly find out if uploaded PDF / Image is in proper format and it gives error message to a user. ?

Comment: `latexmk` is a perl build script, AFAIK is has no tools to examine PDF files. There it is better to use other tools to see what the security meta data says.

Comment: I found this, i dont know how do i only get bolean return
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394023/how-to-determine-if-a-pdf-page-exists-before-including-it

Comment: That is part of the latex processing, it has nothing to do with what `latexmk` does. Since you're writing in PHP why don't you use PHP and other external tools to examine the PDF to see if there might be issues with it. As I mentioned this is not really a job for latex it self.

Comment: ok, let me have a look to PDF libraries. thankyou