# How to read %%Pages:... from *.xbb file

Tags: graphics, pdf

Given the auxiliary file `test.xbb`

```
%%Title: test.pdf
%%Creator: extractbb 20180506
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 300 343
%%HiResBoundingBox: 0.000000 0.000000 300.290000 342.810000
%%PDFVersion: 1.4
%%Pages: 17
%%CreationDate: Mon Jan  7 18:06:49 2019
```

produced from input file `test.pdf` using the `extractbb` utility

```
extractbb test.pdf
```

---

Is there an easy way to read the value of the `%%Pages:` key from `test.xbb` by means of some internal command defined in the `graphics` package? I know that `graphics` parses user provided `xbb` files in order to determine bounding-box coordinates for binary-type or compressed image files that TeX cannot read on its own. Can it do the same for `%%Pages:` out of the box?

Comment: Are you interested in [Get number of pages of external PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198091/5764)?

Comment: Yes, but without using `pdftex`, `luatex`, `xetex`, just by reading `xbb` while running `(pdf|lua)latex` in DVI mode.

Comment: I see nothing in the code. It wouldn't imho be very difficult to add it, but can't you read the xbb yourself?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer : Thank you. It would be nice if such a thing would already exist, but maybe I will have to homebrew something myself based on `graphics` code.

Comment: actually main thing you'd have to change is the code that makes it stop reading the file once it has found a bounding box.... although if you know it's a xbb file with that format rather than arbitrary eps file, it might be as easy to simply \input it rather than use the `\read` loop from graphics

Comment: @David , do you mean `\input{test.xbb}`? It's all commented lines, does it read anything at all?

Comment: `%` doesn't have to be a comment....

Comment: @David , I see, catcodes and such...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


{%
\def\%#1:#2@{\expandafter\xdef\csname ZZ#1\endcsname{#2}}%
\endlinechar`\@ %
\catcode`\%=0 \sbox0{\input{test.xbb}}}%


Pages: \ZZPages
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you please explain why `\input` must be placed  into an sbox? To prevent any typeset output?

Comment: @AlexG try without:-) yes as you say it throws away any accidental typeset result, in fact you get a typeset `@` from  the final newline, which could be avoided in other ways but....

Comment: Ok. Very smart! And what about the double percent sign in the input? I can see only one `%` in `\def\%...`

Comment: @AlexG if `%` has catcode 0 (escape character ) then `%%` references the same command  as `\%`  the command with name `%` just as `\\  ` references the command with name `\ `

Comment: Thank you, @David. I think I got it (after 5 reads or so :-) ).

Comment: What is the sense of the % (=escape chars) at the end of the lines?