# How to get number of pages of external pdf file in Lualatex?

Tags: luatex, pdf

I tried all the answers I could find about this topic, and can't get something to work.

This MWE works OK, but only in pdflatex, since `\pdfximage` do not work in lualatex.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\pdfximage{index.pdf}%
\the\pdflastximagepages
\end{document}
```

Answers in [Get number of pages of external PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198091/get-number-of-pages-of-external-pdf)

do not work, here is the code from the above link:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\pdfnumberofpages}[1]{%
  \directlua{%
    local doc = epdf.open("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}")
    local pages
    if (doc) then
      pages = doc:getCatalog():getNumPages()
    else
      pages = 0
    end
    tex.write(pages)
  }%
}

\begin{document}
Number of pages: \pdfnumberofpages{index.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Now, `lulatex foo.tex` gives

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./foo.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
\pdfnumberofpages ...open("\luatexluaescapestring
                                                  {#1}") local pages if (doc...

l.17 Number of pages: \pdfnumberofpages{test.pdf}
```

What is the correct way to obtain the number of pdf pages of external PDF file using **lualatex** ?

Using TL 2019 on Linux.

Comment: The linked answer is from 2014 which was when LuaTeX was still in beta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pdftex primitives are not gone, they have only been renamed: `\pdfximage` is `\saveimageresource`, and `\pdflastximagepages` is `\lastsavedimageresourcepages`. So:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\saveimageresource{index.pdf}%
\the\lastsavedimageresourcepages
\end{document}
```

Or you could load the `luatex85` package, and then use the pdftex primitives, so that the document compiles with both pdflatex and lualatex.

Comment: What would be the the best way to extract this value into lua?
`token.get_macro('lastsavedimageresourcepages')` returns `nil`

Comment: @likethevegetable `local p = "\the\lastsavedimageresourcepages"` ? Or use the `pdfe` library as per Henri's alternative answer.

Answer (score 6):

The `epdf` library (based on poppler) has been replaced by the `pdfe` library (based on pplib).  Further you did not define `\luatexluaescapestring`, you must have meant `\luaescapestring`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\pdfnumberofpages}[1]{%
  \directlua{%
    local pages = 0
    local doc = pdfe.open("\luaescapestring{#1}")
    if doc then
      pages = pdfe.getnofpages(doc)
      pdfe.close(doc)
    end
    tex.write(pages)
  }%
}

\begin{document}
Number of pages: \pdfnumberofpages{index.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, I thought this was about the Lua end.  Nevermind, I'll leave it here for future readers.