# \lastsavedimageresourcepages in lua

Tags: luatex, pdf, lua

I am attempting to get the total number of pages of an external PDF document as a lua variable through

```
\saveimageresource{index.pdf}%
\the\lastsavedimageresourcepages
```

see: [How to get number of pages of external pdf file in Lualatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518471/how-to-get-number-of-pages-of-external-pdf-file-in-lualatex)

However, when i call the lua code, the returned value is nil.

`token.get_macro('lastsavedimageresourcepages')` returns `nil`

I also tried `tex.count['lastsavedimageresourcepages']` but it throws an error.

Comment: `\directlua{tex.print(tex.lastsavedimageresourcepages)} `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
tex.lastsavedimageresourcepages
```

to access the value from Lua

Comment: Thank you. Is there a function like `tex.saveimageresource` also? The luatex manual does not seem to make this clear.

Comment: @likethevegetable I think that's `img.write(img.scan{ file = "foo.pdf" })` (luatex manual section 11.1.8)