# How to include only odd pages or even pages using pdfpages?

Tags: pdfpages

Is there any better solution to include all odd / even pages of a pdf file?

```
    \documentclass{scrartcl} 
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    
    \begin{document}
    \includepdf[page={1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27
    %\includepdf[page={2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28
    }]{bCh03.pdf}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a direct solution within the pdfpages package. However, you can do this with a loop.

First you would extract the number of pages (cf. [this answer by Symbol 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198095/229797)) by

```
\pdfximage{bCh03.pdf}
```

This stores the number of pages in the macro *\pdflastximagepages*, which will be required for the termination criterion. Next you need a loop. For this, create the iterator *int* like this

```
\newcounter{int}
\setcounter{int}{-1}
```

Then you start the loop and insert only the page corresponding to the counter

```
\whiledo{\not{\value{int} > \pdflastximagepages}}{
\includepdf[page={\theint}]{bCh03.pdf}
\addtocounter{int}{2}
}
```

If you want to add only even pages, initialize *int* as 2. If you want every third page to appear, increment the counter by 3. In this fashion, you can simply define an own macro

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\newcounter{int}
\newcommand{\myincludepdf}[3]{
    \pdfximage{#1}
    \setcounter{int}{#2}
    \whiledo{\not{\value{int} > \pdflastximagepages}}{
        \includepdf[page={\theint}]{#1}
        \addtocounter{int}{#3}}
}


\begin{document}
    \myincludepdf{bCh03.pdf}{1}{2}
\end{document}
```