# Extracting two last page from a beamer pdf respectif the original format

Tags: beamer, pdfpages

I want to extract the two or three last pages from a beamer produced pdf respecting the original format.

I have no idea how to select the two last pages and witch documentclass to use to respect the original format : both beamer and article go wrong.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=last]{file.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no interface to access the last page number.

Comment: As pdfpages knows the last page and last-1 lists all the pages in revers order, I try to know if there is some thing as : last - (last-1).

Comment: With a fresher mind after a night's sleep, I remembered I already solved the problem.

Comment: What problem haven't you already solved ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{l3graphics}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\settotalpagestomacro{mm}{\graphics_get_pagecount:nN {#1}#2}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{xfp}

\NewDocumentCommand\includelastpages{O{1}m}{%
  \bgroup%
  \settotalpagestomacro{#2}\lastpage%
  \edef\prevlastpage{\fpeval{max(1,\lastpage-#1+1)}}%
  \includepdf[pages=\prevlastpage-\lastpage,fitpaper]{#2}%
  \egroup%
}

\begin{document}
\includelastpages[2]{file1.pdf}
\includelastpages[4]{file2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The `\settotalpagestomacro` uses recent version of `l3graphics` to get number of pages (see this answer [Get number of pages of external PDF](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/641479/14500)).

The `fitpaper` option adjusts the paper size to the one of the inserted document.

The `\includelastpages` macro includes the last pages from a PDF file. The optional argument defines the number of pages (default value: 1).